# Sql Join On Field But Split Value First By Delimiter And Use Part Only

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, count

I have a number of SKU's for sold/invoiced products in a database table, but some of the SKU's have extra data appended at the end of the SKU delimited by a pipe (Could be many pipes after base sku). i.e. I could have the same product SKU like this

```
correct-product-sku
correct-product-sku|assembled
correct-product-sku|assembled|custom
etc...
```

I want to join the product table against the invoice table like so.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalCount, productVariant.productKey
FROM invoiceItem
INNER JOIN productVariant ON invoiceItem.sku = productVariant.sku
```

But this will only join on the base SKU `correct-product-sku` and will ignore the others.

Is there an efficient way to split the `invoiceItem.sku` by the `|` and then use only the first part `[0]`. Obviously the SKU won't always have a `|` in it or could have one or many appended.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't store such values in the first place. This violates the most fundamental design principle, the 1st Normal Form. Even if you split those strings, joining on those values can't use any strings and the query will have to scan *all* rows to find matches

Comment: Fix the bad design first: you can create a new SKU column and store only the left part of that "smart" key there using eg `LEFT(notSKU,charindex('|',notSKU)-1)`. You could make this an indexed computed column.

Comment: Another significant improvement would be to use a [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver15) column to store the parts hierarchy. At a very high conceptual level it's the same hierarchical path. It takes far less space though, comes with built-in functions and indexing support and makes it easy to find children, parents, levels etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CHARINDEX and LEFT function as below to join your columns-

> Code is bit edited considering if the Sku column hold only the real value without having any | in it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalCount, productVariant.productKey
FROM invoiceItem
INNER JOIN productVariant 
ON LEFT(
    invoiceItem.sku,
        CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX('|',invoiceItem.sku,0) = 0 THEN  LEN(invoiceItem.sku)
            ELSE CHARINDEX('|',invoiceItem.sku,0) -1
        END
) = productVariant.sku
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest the substring function but Left is more clear in this situation:

```
substring(invoiceItem.sku, 1, charindex('|', invoiceItem.sku)-1)
```

If the sku has a fixed length you can use the length instead of the charindex funtion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalCount, pv.productKey
FROM invoiceItem it INNER JOIN
     productVariant pv
     ON pv.sku LIKE i.sku + '|%'
GROUP BY pv.productKey;
```